# Trying to remove all characters on the right after space or tab

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running a code to download text from the internet.

I'm looking for an easy way to only leave the IP addresses and save it to a file.

No matter what I try to strip the right part of each line it doesn't work. I think the space in the response is a tab, but even when I tried it didn't do anything.

I've tried `strip` and `rstrip` with different combinations with no luck.

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/ipsum/master/ipsum.txt")
print(response.text.rstrip(' '))
```

I'm expecting to only see IP addresses line by line like this:

```
171.25.193.25 

89.234.157.254

171.25.193.77
```

But, instead the output looks something like this :

```
171.25.193.25   14

89.234.157.254  12

171.25.193.77   12

171.25.193.235  12

171.25.193.20   12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your whole request is treated as one string, the split would not work properly. Thus, you have to divide the request into line by line and do the split for each line such as

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/ipsum/master/ipsum.txt")
lines = response.text.split('\n')[4:] # ignore 4 lines.
for line in lines:
    print(line.split()[0])
```

which will gives you the result as below.

```
171.25.193.25
89.234.157.254
171.25.193.77
...
```

Comment: Thank you This is exactly what i was looking for . The only thing is that the last print goes out of index   print(line.split()[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I will check it when I return to home :) But you can try with this `lines = response.text.split('\n')[4:-1]`.

Comment: Perfect . that fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you may use a `split` function.

The `str.split()` method without an argument splits on whitespace:

try `print(response.text.split()[0])`

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stamparm/ipsum/master/ipsum.txt")
response = response.text.split()
response = "\n".join([x for x in response if '.' in x])
print(response)
```

This is how I suggest solution.